# iOS Cocoa pod Eureka: How to add an CheckRow list and a button

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

I want to create a view that contain a section with list of options and another row with a "go next button"

But the example code in the GitHub of Eureka does not tell you how to do it. Thats because the example is a empty page with just the checkbox rows and nothing else. When a try to put a button in another section of that view I get the following error:

> +++ is not a prefix unary operator

My example class is:

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class PaymentView: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setForm()
    }

    func onNext() {
        print("go to review!")
    }

    func setForm() {
        form

        +++ SelectableSection<ListCheckRow<String>>("Elige la forma de pago:", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: true))

        let paymentMethods = ["Dinero en efectivo", "Datafast"]
        for option in paymentMethods {
            (self.form.last!) <<< ListCheckRow<String>(option){ listRow in
                listRow.title = option
                listRow.selectableValue = option
                listRow.value = nil
            }
        }

        +++ Section("Footer")
            <<< ButtonRow(){
                $0.title = "Elegir método de pago"
                }
                .onCellSelection { [weak self] (cell, row) in
                    if row.section?.form?.validate().count == 0{
                        self?.onNext()
                    }
                    else {
                        print("The form has errors")
                    }

                    // End form
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else has the same problem. The solution is this:
Before appending a new section or table row item use (self.form) to continue the chain of the the Eureka form generator. It looks like this:

```
(self.form) +++ Section("button")
// rest of your code
```